# What should I learn first? (For web programming)

Tags: javascript, programming-languages

Should I learn PHP or JQuery.I have some knowledge in HTML CSS and JavaScript.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*What types of questions should I avoid asking?*](/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modern web development is now actually divided in to two major parts

1. Frontend (JavaScript and related things)
2. Backend (PHP, NodeJS or others)

Now if you are more interested in designing the User Interface and what shows on the screen, then go forward to HTML and then JavaScipt and then JQuery (which is an opensource library in JavaScript) and then CSS.
However if you are interested in Backend (means server side coding, databases and business logics etc) then you should target PHP or any other suitable server side language.

**Bonus**: If you are interested in starting things quickly, I would recommend that start learning JavaScript first, because there is a server side technology named NodeJS (which does almost all the work PHP does) and it uses JavaScript. So in that case, you only will have to learn JavaScript and CSS.

Answer (score 0):

They are for different purposes. JQuery is for Front End, that means, what will run on users's browsers. The same goes for HTML and CSS. PHP is what will run on the server.

If you are extremely newbie, just as I was a few years ago, you might want to learn them all at the same time. Also, SQL, as it is the language for databases.

This site is for beginners: http://www.w3schools.com/